# How TO - Align Images Side By Side

Tags: html, css

[image: How they show up now]I am following this tutorial on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp). I am creating a social site and I want to show users an explore page and I want the images to be side by side maybe 3 or 4 pics a row and then break and then show another 3 or 4. Right now it's completely off. [image: How it shows].

As you can see, it is on top of each other and it is all on the right side of the page. What am I missing ? I want it to show exactly how it looks on the example.

```
<div class="row">
<?php

    // output data of each row
    while ($explore_image->fetch()) {

        if ($userLoggedIn != $added_by) {

            if (!empty($image)) {
                echo '<div class="row"><div class="explore_column">';
                echo "<a href='$image'><img src='$image' ></a><p> $added_by $likes </p></br><br><br><br></div></div><br>";
            }
        }
    }
    
    $explore_image->close();
    $con->close();

?>
</div>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
display: flex;
}

/* Create three equal columns that sits next to each other */
.explore_column {
flex: 100.33%;
padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.explore_column {
width: 100%;
}
}

/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */
.explore_column {
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
padding: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
```

Comment: give code you already have, otherwise moderators will close this question

Comment: Oh wow I forgot to post it

Comment: @chojnicki I updated it

Comment: Get rid of the `<br>` at the end of the line, that is causing the new line

Comment: @imvain2 tried moving that one and all of the other and it made no difference

Comment: So the `<br>` was probably part of the problem but I do see another problem: `flex: 100.33%;` should be `flex: 33.33%;`. 33.33% allows for 3 columns, 100.33% is one full screen width plus a little extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to implement styling as below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
img {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg"/>
</div>
```

---

You can adjust the % to your needs.

Comment: That shows them on top of each other. None show up next to each other

Comment: When you run the snippet, you should see two rows of 4 images and 2 images. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah and I did it on an example page in my project its fine. I think it's something wrong with the php code

Comment: This is how my php looks `<?php

  // output data of each row
  while ($explore_image->fetch()) {

   if ($userLoggedIn != $added_by) {

       if (!empty($image)) {
        echo '<div class="explore">';
        echo "<a href='$image'><img src='$image' ></a></div>";
       }
      }
  }
  
  $explore_image->close();
  $con->close();

 ?>`

Comment: I think you could try moving div with class `explore` outside of the `while` loop, then inside the loop, add only the images so that you can use the above styling. What you want to have is 1 outer div (parent) and nested children - your images. Right now you are creating multiple `div` elements with images right inside each of them.

Comment: You need to make sure there is no other styling that is involved other than what is above. In your case, the styling for div would be the styling for class `explore` and then you could add a new class for images like `class="explore_image"`, then implement the styling for an image within that class to make sure you do not use some other styling from the application. You can inspect and see what kind of styling is currently being used and whether the structure is similar to the above one from the answer. I still assume that you only add images in a loop and that you have 1 outer `div`.

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question, providing specific code example, and asking about that, other people might want to find it helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub said, keep the display set to flex, but also add

```
flex-direction: row;
```

that might help